# Match first URL in string via regex for yahoo pipes

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I am using Yahoo Pipes and trying to manipulate a link from an RSS feed.  The feed has the URL format like this:

```
http://domainone.com?blahblahblah?url=http://otherdomain.com/the_rest_of_the_link
```

Using the pipes regex module I would like to search for the second link in the string and remove the first.  The resulting string would be: "http://otherdomain.com/the_rest_of_the_link" to the END of the line.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=operators#Regex):
[image]

And you can use this **regex** for your need:

`(http:\/\/.*){2}`

Check here: http://rubular.com/r/zRZOLX5j54